# Call ASP.NET Web API in Angular 8 not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, angular, typescript

For reference I'm using SQL Server, EF 6 and Angular 8. My entities are customer, product and wishlist (has `wishId`, `userId` and `productId`). But my code is not working, can you guys help?

Controller:

```
    [Route("AddToWishlist")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult AddToWishlist(WishList wishlist)
    {
        db.WishList.Add(wishlist);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

`product.service.ts`:

```
getWishlist() {
 return this.http.get(wishlistUrl).pipe(
       map((result: any[]) => {
            let productIds = []

              result.forEach(item => productIds.push(item.id))

   return productIds;
   })
  )
  }

addToWishlist(productId) {
     return this.http.post(wishlistUrl, { id: productId })
}

removeFromWishlist(productId) {
   return this.http.delete(wishlistUrl + '/' + productId);
}
```

`product.component.ts`:

```
handleAddToWishlist() {
   this.wishlistService.addToWishlist(this.productItem.id).subscribe(() => { 
   this.addedToWishlist = true;
 })
}

 handleRemoveFromWishlist() {
   this.wishlistService.removeFromWishlist(this.productItem.id).subscribe(() => {
   this.addedToWishlist = false;
})
```

}

`product.component.html`:

```
<i *ngIf="addedToWishlist" class="fas fa-heart float-right" 
(click)="handleRemoveFromWishlist()"></i>
<i *ngIf="!addedToWishlist" class="far fa-heart float-right" 
(click)="handleAddToWishlist()"></i>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Check if your call is not getting blocked by CORS. Have you added CORS middleware in your startup file?

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing I noticed and can point you in the right direction for other API calls

Your add to wishlist, you are only passing 'id' when you mentioned the API is expecting wishId

```js
addToWishlist(productId) {
     return this.http.post(wishlistUrl, { wishId: productId })
}
```

Other recommendations

Create [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object#:%7E:text=In%20the%20field%20of%20programming,call%20is%20an%20expensive%20operation.) objects for each of your entities.

API - WishListInfo.cs

```cs
public class WishListInfo {
 public int wishId { get; set; }
}
```

UI (interface or class)

```js
export class WishListInfo {
 wishId: number;
}
```

Now you can update your call to your api as follows

```js
addToWishlist(wish: WishListInfo) { <- You will set this object before making this call.
     return this.http.post(wishlistUrl, wish)
}
```

```cs
[Route("AddToWishlist")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult AddToWishlist(WishListInfo wishlist)
    {
        db.WishList.Add(wishlist);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

many things can cause this code not working I'll mention here some cases and try them may this will help:-

- in the backend method AddToWishlist didn't have an error handle since this entity has three fields and you post only { id: productId } this will make ef save changes fail
- from google chrome press f12 and select network to monitor network requests to see requests and responses received from the backend and if you find that network response as expected this will guide you that the reason can be in display part in angular script
- finally if previous not work from f12 select consol to see if there ay consol error may you find any script error or cors block